# SASS Duplicating/Renaming a class containing map

Tags: css, sass, sass-maps

I have an existing SASS map that looks like this:

```
@each $color, $value in $theme-colors {
  .old-name-#{$color} {
      color: $value;
  }
}
```

I want to keep .old-name in my CSS but create a new alias with new naming. For other areas I'm just using:

```
.new-name { 
  @extend .old-name;
}
```

How does it work in the syntax when you want to extend a class with a map? Is something like this possible?

```
.new-name-#($color) { 
  @extend .old-name-#($color);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is perfectly possible to extends the selectors you created using maps.

```scss
@each $color, $value in $theme-colors {
  .old-name-#{$color} {
    color: $value;
  }
}

@each $color, $value in $theme-colors {
  .new-name-#{$color} {
    @extend .old-name-#{$color};
  }
}
```